# How to query something from an array using WHERE in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried the code below, but it does not work.

```
spark.sql("""SELECT categories, business_id 
FROM business_data 
WHERE categories = 'Ice Cream'
""").show(150, truncate=False)
```

It seems like there is a different way to query from an array but I cant figure it out.
This is what my data looks like.

Sample data:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Hi. It is generally poor relational design to have columns of a type if you are generically querying re the parts of values of that type. If the type `categories` is an array then your `where` is ill-typed, and if it is a string with commas in it then your `where` is asking for the entire string to be `'ice cream'`. Why would you expect differently? Unfortunately you are too informal, it's not clear what the types of values or their parts are. Similarly, you have not explained "does not work", etc, what you want or what you expect. Explain yourself clearly. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: PS [Use text, not links/images, for text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3404097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Specific:
[FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

---

FROM DOCS:

Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by , characters. If the first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type SET, the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic. Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string. Returns NULL if either argument is NULL. This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (,) character.

`mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');`

---

So in your case...

```
spark.sql("""SELECT categories, business_id 
FROM business_data 
WHERE Find_In_set('Ice Cream',categories)>1
""").show(150, truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you want to query something out of an Array you would use array_contains, as such:

```
SELECT business_id, categories
FROM business_data
WHERE array_contains(categories,'Ice Cream & Frozen Yogurt')
```